# Div tag width too long and cant be decreased

Tags: html, css, media-queries, media

im trying to alter media queries in order to get html responsive on alternate platforms. The width of a div tag is causing a horizontal scroll and It wont seem to decrease.

it says its 396 X 3523 whatever i do.

```
.columns{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    width: auto;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
```

}

Comment: A single CSS definition is not sufficient information to diagnose your problem.  Please review [ask] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55872221/edit) your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Did you try giving it a width other than 'auto'? Such as "width: 100%;"

Comment: Whats inside the div?

Answer (score 1):

adding max-width: 100% should fix that;